# VMWare copied VM not booting: panic kernel

Tags: kernel, vmware, boot, panic

After copied a Linux virtual machine (the folder itself, there's not a snapshot option) created with **VMWare Workstation Player 12** to another computer it doesn't boot, it shows a message kernel panic and neither the default kernel nor the other one works.

Both computers have Intel i7 cpu's. Not the exact same, though, but same architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we used [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) instead of VMWare Workstation to load the VMWare Workstation virtual machine.

We created a new virtual machine and set up as disk the copied Virtual Machine (.vmdk file) and it works fine without any other tuning.